Which shapes are classically good for fairing instersections?
I'm fairing a strut/wing interface (pictured in blue in the below screenshots), and I realized while it makes sense to continue in the lift strut's profile to the wing on the shallow angle, I don't have an instinct of how should be the area in the acute angle formed by the lift strut and the wing.
Are there classically ideal shapes for acute intersections beyond some kind of fillet?
A fillet strikes me as something which would be very bizarre here, as the fillet would have to extend both forward and behind the lift strut, adding significant wetted area to the fairing (although at the same time removing some wetted area from the interface).



Normally, you let the fillet radius grow in flow direction. At the nose, the radius is near zero and becomes gradually larger towards the trailing edge.

@PeterKämpf do you have a link to some examples of that? Extending the loft in the direction of the lift strut is easy, but the part that bends back almost 150 degrees isn't making sense to me with the description in your comment.

Chapter 8.4 of Hörner might be helpful.

When in doubt, copy something in use.


Agreed! But only insomuch as there's data showing it works. Is there any for those kind of fairings? That fairing strikes me as aftermarket, and so it could be as much driven by aesthetics as aerodynamics.

Data may be scarce for an ideal fairing, because when low drag really matters, the airplane doesn't have struts at all.  Can we find an upper bound for the drag of a poor fairing, as a fraction of the whole strut's drag?
